# Horizontal scrolling in PDF files with Default dictionary functionality in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiwebview

I am trying to display PDF in `UIWebView` with horizontal scrolling. But, I don't know how to show in horizontal scroll. PDF working fine in vertical scrolling with **COPY DEFINE SHARE** functionality. So I referred for horizontal scroll. I found some links for horizontal with page curl effect. There, each and every pages convert into images and then it showed in **UIScrollView/UICollectionView/UIPageViewController**. So if I try to copy a single word from PDF, I failed. Because, it is image file.

In, `UIWebView` `QLPreviewController` `UIDocumentInteraction`, files are scrolling in vertical.

1. How can I change to horizontal scroll?

or

1. How can I select a word to go for default dictionary in Page curl effect?

**Screen Shot:**

[image]